# ZeroMQ: publish to many, receive replys in any order

Tags: python, node.js, multithreading, sockets, zeromq

I'm learning about the ZeroMQ patterns, and I need to implement the following:

NodeJS will **send messages to many python threads**, but it doesn't need to wait for the answers synchronously, they **can come in any order**. I know that the publish/subscribe pattern solves it in one way: it can send to many, but how do the python workers send the reply back?

Also, in order for the python threads to receive the message, which is the better design: the python process receives the message and sends to the appropriate thread (don't know how to do it), or each thread is responsible to receive its own messages?

Comment: For the first one, I think you can try router-dealer. It's two-way and async.

Answer (score 0):

There's no obligation to use a single socket for the two way comms. Two is perfectly fine.

This means you can have PUB/SUB to broadcast from your NodeJS to your Python code. That's the easy part. Then have a separate PUSH/PULL socket back the other way - the Python does the pushing, the NodeJS does the pulling. One PUSH socket per Python thread, and just one PULL socket in the NodeJS (it will pull from any of the push sockets). Thus whenever one of the Python threads wants to send something to the NodeJS, it simply sends it through the PUSH socket.

AFAIK the NodeJS can 'bind' it's PULL socket, and the Python can 'connect' it's PUSH socket, which is something you can do if one wants to feel that the NodeJS is the 'server'. Though this is unecessary - either end can bind, so long as the other end connects. Remember though that ZeroMQ is Actor model programming; there is no clients or servers, there's just actors. 'Bind' and 'connect' are only mentioned at all because it's all implemented on top of tcp (or similar), and it's the tcp transport that has to be told who's binding and connecting.

Have each thread responsible for its own socket. Though given that Python threads aren't real threads you're not going to get a speed-up through having them (unless they've gone and got rid of the global interpretter lock since I last looked). The ZeroMQ context itself sets up a thread(s) which marshalls all the actual message transfers in the background, so the IO is already significantly overlapped.